# Андроид VerifyError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, исключения

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые! Начал писать первое приложение под андроид. При попытке запуска приложение крашится, даже не заходя в onCreate. Под отладкой я попадаю в метод

```
public InvocationTargetException(Throwable exception) {
    super(null, exception);
    target = exception;
}
```

где **exception** это исключение **java.lang.VerifyError**. В Интернете прочитал, что VerifyError может быть связано с тем, что какие-то из используемых методов могут не поддерживаться в выбранной версии sdk и что нужно открыть LogCat и посмотреть информацию там. Я новичок в Eclipse, поэтому, может, что-то делаю не так, но когда я открываю LogCat, то там совершенно пусто. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Что-то вы делаете определенно не так, но, исходя из того, что вы написали, определить, что именно, невозможно. Думаю, что можно посмотреть пару видеоуроков типа "программирование под Андроид для начинающих", где описывается работа с Эклипсом.